# browser doesn't show progress bar when downloading a file using javascript

Tags: javascript

browser doesn't show progress bar when downloading a file

```
function getSound(sound) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", sound, true);
    req.responseType = "blob";
    req.onload = function (event) {
        var blob = req.response;//if you have the fileName header available
        var link=document.createElement('a');
        link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download='sound.mp3';
        link.click();
    };
    req.send();
}
```

I want show like this
[image: I want show like this]

Comment: Can you also add current behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that by the time you call 'click' the file is already downloaded. But you didn't need to download the file in advance:

```js
function getSound(sound) {
  const link=document.createElement('a');
  link.href=sound;
  link.download='sound.mp3';
  link.click();
}
```

Comment: from this method, It navigate to another page. but I need to download withing the same page

Comment: @Lakmi is the link on a different domain than your website? If it's on the same domain it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add [Content-Lenght](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length) header to let the web browser know the size of your file.